# NSInternalInconsistencyException UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I'm getting the following exception:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view
>   of kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter with identifier footer -
>   must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a
>   prototype cell in a storyboard'

in function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "footer", for: indexPath)
        return footerView
}
```

I'm registering footer view like this:

```
collectionView.register(UICollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "footer")
```

I've added CollectionReusableView into CollectionView in storyboard:

[image]

[image]

Everything seems alright, but crash pops out, why?

Comment: If you are using a storyboard, out the reuse identifier in the storyboard item and there is no need to register anything in code.

Comment: I thought that as well, but I've found *I have to add it* so I've added it. Without registering I'm getting the same exception.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your storyboard

Comment: But what could be wrong? I've selected Section Footer in CollectionView in Storyboard and footer view itself is just a view with activity indicator inside it. Not really fancy stuff, as simple as possible.

Comment: maybe duplicated identifiers registered: one from storyboard and one from your code

Comment: I checked that out and there aren't any duplicates. Anyway... nevermind.. I've just added special cell at the end without using footer and it's working fine.